# Не отправляет данные AJAX

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите почему AJAX не отправляет id дива с классом poid обработчику ?!Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема! Заранее спасибо!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{

$('#photoimg').live('change', function() 
 {
var A=$("#imageloadstatus");
var B=$("#imageloadbutton");
var x = $('.poid').attr('id');
var z= x;
var dataString = '&z=' +z;
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview',

beforeSubmit:function(){
A.show();
B.hide();
}, 
success:function(){
A.hide();
B.show();
}, 
error:function(){
A.hide();
B.show();
} }).submit();
});
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxImageUpload.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
});
});

</script>
```

Вот как принимаем обработчик

```
$poid=$_POST['z'];
```

Comment:     var dataString = '&z=' +z;

Попробуйте убрать &, он не нужен в начале строки данных. Возможно, проблема в этом.

Comment: Заменил, но данные так же не приходят

Comment: Откройте консоль браузера и посмотрите, какие данные передаются в POST. Например, [так][1].


  [1]: http://cs317131.vk.me/v317131798/77a2/zFIxYl5MDnI.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Понятное дело, не будет работать. Во первых ajax запрос у тебя отправляется сразу. Код то нужно держать в приличном виде.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    // событие на изменение элемента #photoimg
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
        var A = $("#imageloadstatus");
        var B = $("#imageloadbutton");
        var x = $('.poid').attr('id');
        var z = x;
        var dataString = '&z=' +z;

        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview',
            beforeSubmit:function(){
                A.show();
                B.hide();
            }, 
            success:function(){
                A.hide();
                B.show();
            }, 
            error:function(){
                A.hide();
                B.show();
            } 
        }).submit();
    });

    // после события dom ready (загрузки страницы) отправляется Ajax запрос
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxImageUpload.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
    });
});
```

По сути у тебя просто не определена переменная `dataString`, т.к. она определяется внутри функции, которая навешана на событие `change` у элемента `#photoimg` и вообще с внешним миром не общается.

Если у тебя `ajax` запрос отправляется не в функции, которая весит на событии `change`, то нужно вынести переменную `dataString` в функцию, которая весит на событии `dom ready`, т.е.:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
            var dataString = '&z=' +z;
```

Дальше следует понять, что переменная `dataString` не изменится до тех пор, пока не произойдет событие `change` у элемента `#photoimg`. После этого собития уже можно отправлять ajax запрос зная, что переменная не пустая.

Конечный вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    // событие на изменение элемента #photoimg
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
        var A = $("#imageloadstatus");
        var B = $("#imageloadbutton");
        var x = $('.poid').attr('id');
        var z = x;
        var dataString = '&z=' +z;

        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview',
            beforeSubmit:function(){
                A.show();
                B.hide();
            }, 
            success:function(){
                A.hide();
                B.show();

                // когда получен ответ от сервера, можно делать ajax запрос
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxImageUpload.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                });
            }, 
            error:function(){
                A.hide();
                B.show();
            } 
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Вообще не понял, что запрос там не в событии. В следующий раз надо будет отдавать код блокноту и приводить к читаемому виду, прежде чем отвечать на вопрос. Плюс вам, за урок.

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "ajaxImageUpload.php"
```

А путь верно определили? Наверное вам лучше скинуть весь код, не только ajax запроса. Тогда больше вероятность, что вам ответят.

Comment: Нет, скрипт который в обработчике выполняется, ему переменная только не доходит